# Python Pandas Add a Row to a Multi-Indexed Datafrane

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm trying to add a single row (actually a value) to a multiindexed dataframe.  The first level of the index is a string and the second is a timestamp.

I cannot seem to get the syntax down to add a new row.  The problem is with the timestamp.

So I have:

```
                        PRICE         RETURN  
Symbol      ModelDate                                    
A           2017-03-31  52.5278     -0.006472        
            2017-04-03  52.8556      0.006241
```

If I try to add another row to this dataframe like this:

```
add_date = Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00', freq='D')
symbol = 'A'

df.loc[(symbol, add_date),:]
```

and I want to get:

```
                        PRICE         RETURN  
Symbol      ModelDate                                    
A           2017-03-31  52.5278     -0.006472        
            2017-04-03  52.8556      0.006241   
            2017-04-03    Nan          Nan
```

I get:

```
KeyError: (u'A', Timestamp('2017-04-04 00:00:00', freq='D'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: If I do `df.info()` the return includes:

```
MultiIndex: 64 entries, (A, 2017-03-31 00:00:00) to (Z, 2017-05-30 00:00:00)
```

Comment: you're looking up a value that's not in the index so it's giving you a KeyError

Comment: I've tried to `append` it as well and it tells me my multiindex value is not unique - but it is!  How would I add the row?

Answer (score 1):

```
add_date = pd.to_datetime('2017-04-04 00:00:00')
symbol = 'A'
df.loc[(symbol, add_date),:]=np.nan
df
Out[538]: 
                     PRICE    RETURN
Symbol ModelDate                    
A      2017-03-31  52.5278 -0.006472
       2017-04-03  52.8556  0.006241
       2017-04-04      NaN       NaN
```

Comment: When I try this I get `cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`.  But it IS a unique value!

Comment: My `add_date` is already a timestamp as are the values in the second level of the index.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 if you can get the same output by using your sample data as I did , your original data set must have some issue.

Comment: I will check.  Thank you!